# Pull users access level from database and add to session

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, acl

I am working on a simple PHP & MySQL application and have been asked to add in simple ACL functionality with 3 access levels, admin (can do it all), editor (can add and edit data) and reader (can only read data and make zero edits).

I have assigned each role a value, 1 for admin, 2 for editor and 3 for reader and have added that to the user add form and also the db, what I need now is a way to be able to pull that into the login session so that it can be checked at various levels (menu and some pages).

So far what I have so far is below.

The login function

```
    public function login($username, $password) {

    global $bcrypt;  // Again make get the bcrypt variable, which is defined in init.php, which is included in login.php where this function is called

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `password`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $data               = $query->fetch();
        $stored_password    = $data['password']; // stored hashed password
        $id                 = $data['id']; // id of the user to be returned if the password is verified, below.


        if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){ // using the verify method to compare the password with the stored hashed password.
            return $id; // returning the user's id
        }else{
            return false;   
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

And the login page.

```
<?php
$title = "Login";
require_once 'includes/header.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();
?>

<h1>Login</h1>

<?php 
    if(empty($errors) === false){
        echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';  
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <h4>Username:</h4>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['username']); ?>" />
<h4>Password:</h4>
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Login" />
</form>
<br>
<a href="confirm-recover.php">Forgot your username/password?</a>

<?php
require_once 'includes/footer.php';
if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
} else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
} else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. 
                 Please check your email.';
} else {
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
    }else {
        session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and     creating a new one
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;

        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
} 
?>
```

Hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look below at where i've done "/*EDIT IS HERE */". You need to run session_start(); at the top of the page to initiate the session; It should really be in a Config file. Then you need to pull it from the database and store it in a $_SESSION global variable.

I know from your G+ you're new at PHP. But one of the worst ways of doing PHP is by using inline PHP. It's not necessarily */wrong/* but you should avoid in-line php. Keep your PHP and HTML Separate, it's a lot easier to sort through errors.

```
    public function login($username, $password) {

    global $bcrypt;  // Again make get the bcrypt variable, which is defined in init.php, which is included in login.php where this function is called

    /* EDIT IS HERE */
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `password`, `AccessLevel`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $data               = $query->fetch();
        $stored_password    = $data['password']; // stored hashed password
        $id                 = $data['id']; // id of the user to be returned if the password is verified, below.


        if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){ // using the verify method to compare the password with the stored hashed password.

            /* EDIT IS HERE */
            $_SESSION['AccessLevel'] = $data['AccessLevel'];
            return $id; // returning the user's id
        }else{
            return false;   
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

LOGIN PAGE

```
<?php
$title = "Login";
/* EDIT IS HERE */
session_start();


require_once 'includes/header.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();
?>

<h1>Login</h1>

<?php 
    if(empty($errors) === false){
        echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';  
}
?>
```

BOTTOM OF LOGIN PAGE

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/footer.php';
if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
} else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
} else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. 
                 Please check your email.';
} else {
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
    }else {

        /* EDIT IS HERE */
        //session_regenerate_id(true);
        // destroying the old session id and     creating a new one
        if($_SESSION['AccessLevel'] = "GURU"){

            $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;

            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat.  Have now implemented the access control on the two areas I needed.

Thanks for comment about not using inline PHP, as you said, still a newbie and trying to learn as much as I can.